# Implement a functional processing pipeline with compile-time order constraints

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generic-programming

Let's say we have a data object X and some "processor" objects/methods A, B, C and D. A(X) produces a new X with some additional data (the result of A processing). B(X) produces a new X with some other additional data. C(X) also produces a new X with some additional data but it requires that A has already been ran against X.
So: A(X).B(X).C(X).D(X) should run properly. B(X).D(X).A(X).C(X) should also run properly. B(X).C(X).A(X).D(X) should fail (because C requires the info A produces).

Is this possible to implement in C# so that the order constraints are enforced in compile time? If not, is there a design pattern or some common strategy of how this should be implemented? There can be many processors and many constraints, what I'd like to avoid is having to declare a factorial number of types to keep track of whether a processor has been ran or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inheritance, combined with generic constraints:

```
class Data {
}

class ExtendedData : Data {
}

static class Pipeline {
    public static ExtendedData A<T>(this T value) where T : Data {
        if (value is ExtendedData extended) {
            return extended;
        }
        else {
            return new ExtendedData():
        }
    }

    public static T B<T>(this T value) where T : Data {
        return value;
    }

    public static ExtendedData C(this ExtendedData value) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

These variants will work:

```
new Data().A().B().C();
new Data().B().A().C();
new Data().A().C().B();
```

This variant will be rejected by the compiler:

```
new Data().B().C().A();
```

`C()` will expect an `ExtendedData`, while `B()` will only deliver `Data`.

Comment: But wouldn't that explode in the number of types? What if there's more constraints/data extensions? In this example there's only one constraint so it's easy to implement, but what if we have 10 processors with 6 constraints. Aside from that, C# doesn't support multiple inheritance which adds more problems: We would need to have ExtendedData1 : Data, ExtendedData2 : Data, ExtendedData3 : ExtendedData1, ExtendedData4 : ExtendedData2, ExtendedData5 : ExtendedData3 and so on, to cover all the combinations.

Comment: @DamjanDakic You can use interfaces for multiple constraints. Which would take care of the input types. For the return types you'd have to still specify one specific type. But if the scenario gets more complex you should probably not rely on the compiler. You can use data contracts to define preconditions and postconditions. Some of these contracts might be cauggh by the static checker, the others will be hit early on during testing.

Comment: "For the return types you'd have to still specify one specific type." - this is exactly the problem I'm facing. I would assume from the rest of your comment that it has to be enforced in runtime then?

Comment: @DamjanDakic: As I said, you can look into CodeContracts. There is a static checker that *might* catch some of the constraints. Even if it doesn't you should have improved runtime checking with them.